# ODOO.SH does not redirect http://www. to https://www. properly?

Tags: nginx, ssl, redirect, https, odoo.sh

ODOO.SH provides a basic letsEncryptSSL-certificate for SSL but when you browse on a odoo-sh website (multi-website): http://www.odoosh-website.com, you are not redirected to the corresponding SSL-page: https://www.odoosh-website.com

Support from Odoo.sh has refused to revisit their NGINX-configuration, so that all requests for the http://www.--- address get converted into https://www.--- equivalent addresses.
Although, The answers for other Odoo-hosting look quite straight forward:

```
server {
listen 80;
rewrite ^(.*) https://$host$1 permanent;
}
```

or :

```
 if ($scheme = "http") {
      return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
  }
```

or:

```
server{
  listen 80;
  server_name www.mywebsite.example mydomain.example;
  return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

**Any workaround is welcome !**

Comment: Odoo.sh has at last solved the problem by deleting and reinstalling my domains in odoo.sh,  and explained to me that the issue was caused by the "steps order of my domain-installation"???... which remains mysterious to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Odoo.sh has at last solved the problem by deleting and reinstalling my domains in odoo.sh, and explained to me that the issue was caused by the "steps order of my domain-installation":

<< *From time to time, depending on the order in which the custom domains are configured/created, it can cause a lag in the SSL creation and configurations.
I was able to fix this by deleting the domains on the project page and reentering them.* >>

... which remains mysterious to me